# Safari downloading older version of Silverlight (Getting SL 4 instead of SL 5)

Tags: silverlight-4.0, safari, silverlight-5.0

I have a website using **Silverlight 5**, when an user from Mac wants to visit the site using Safari (because with FF and Chrome it do not work correctly), Safari shows a message: "You need to install Silverlight please click here", when the user clicks on it, Safari starts to download **Silverlight 4**. This means that the user have to unistall that version and go manualy to http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/ and download the correct version (Silverlight 5). How can I solve this problem?, because it is happening for all the mac users.

Comment: I had the correct workflow using Firefox. What 'minimumVersion' setting have you got?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my question formerly I asked. Its closed and down voted. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/q/14746701/413032

Anyway Thank You @ jv42 working with firefox solved my issue.

I'm not sure if my question was is more suitable for SuperUser or StackOverFlow. 
It doesn't matter, It solved. Hope this help someone else.

Its very strange firefox also download same file. But when you install firefox downloaded file  problem goes away ! Weird !